# Why do java binary operations on bytes or chars return an int?

Tags: java, casting, binary-operators

while I was innocently performing some binary operations on bytes in Java, I encountered the following:

[image]

Apparently, byte & byte = int in Java. Same fate for chars.

Longs and booleans, on the other hand, don't suffer from this.

I expected to be able to keep working with bytes without casting.

It seems hackish to have to cast. Is there no more elegant approach?

Why don't I get a byte or char back? Does this have something to do with 32 bit registers and machine code?

Comment: this is done by design

Comment: "Because the standard says so."